# i have issue when call my library in gradle

Tags: android, github, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-2.1

All I have Created My Own Library and I Push That Code in Github, I have Created Library Using JitPack.io but I Face Some Problem When I Call That in My Project Erro is Below :

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
```

> Could not find NewInstllSDK.jar (com.github.sanjay11MP:NewInstllSDK:1.0.4).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jitpack.io/com/github/sanjay11MP/NewInstllSDK/1.0.4/NewInstllSDK-1.0.4.jar

also, You Can See My Library Code : 
https://github.com/sanjay11MP/InstallSDK

and my jitpack log is https://jitpack.io/com/github/sanjay11MP/InstallSDK/1.0.4/build.log

Comment: Is your github page private?
because when I'm trying to check it I got page not found

Comment: no,its not private

Comment: please check this link https://github.com/sanjay11MP/InstallSDK

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your repository name? Your repository name in question is NewInstallSDK, but I have not seen such repository in your profile

Comment: i have edited url also send above comment

Comment: Did you update jitpack?
If yes, can you provide a dependency which I can add into my project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167567/discussion-between-skullper-and-sanjay).

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect project structure. Your project structure is a structure inside a module. You need to push the whole library project to github. Your project should be similiar with this:

```
gradle/wrapper
library
 --- src
 --- .gitignore
 --- build.gradle
 --- proguard-rules.pro
sample
build.gradle
gradle.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
settings.gradle
```

Where `library` is your library module name.

This error:

> ERROR: Gradle wrapper not found. Please add. Using default gradle to
>   build.

means that jitpack.io needs a gradle wrapper which is usually inside project folder as above.

Comment: i have tried this you can see this link https://github.com/sanjay11MP/AllNewProject

Comment: install track is library there

Comment: installtrack can't be accessed. Is it private?

Comment: I have try cloning your project. installtrack is empty folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167694/discussion-between-sanjay-and---).